# How to make all inherited methods return subclass objects?

Tags: perl, oop, inheritance

I'm writting an `hOCR::Element` package on top of [`HTML::Element`](http://metacpan.org/module/HTML::Element) to handle [hOCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HOCR) content. Accordingly, an object from the `hOCR::Element` class inherits all methods belonging to `HTML::Element`.

But as there are a number of essential methods from `HTML::Element` (such as `find_by_tag_name` and `look_down`) that return `HTML::Element` objects, I see myself having to write for each such method a corresponding `hOCR::Element` wrapper method that simply maps by blessing as `hOCR` what it is given as `HTML`.

For example:

```
package hOCR::Element;

use HTML::Element;
use parent 'HTML::Element';

sub new {
  my ($class, %params) = @_;
  my $self = $class->SUPER::new (%params);
  return bless $self, $class;
}

sub look_down { 
  my $self = shift;
  return map { bless $_, 'hOCR::Element' } $self->SUPER::look_down (@_);
}

1;
```

How can I have a subclass inherit all methods from its base class in such a way that those relevant methods return subclass objects instead of base class objects, without having to write a wrapper for each such parent method?

Comment: You could consider writing an [`AUTLOAD`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Autoloading) subroutine instead of inheriting from `HTML::Element`, but that's a little ugly

Comment: Thanks. Would it be just ugly or could it get me into real trouble later?

Comment: I don't see any hazards

Comment: Also take a look at Class::Method::Modifiers. You can pass those a list. It's less ugly than AUTOLOAD,, but a bit more work and less flexible. I'm on a phone, so no like today.

Answer (score -2):

```
sub look_down { 
    my $self = shift;
    return bless $self->SUPER::look_down (@_) ,HTML::Element ;
}
```

Comment: The OP asks for a solution *"without having to write a wrapper for each such parent method"*